# Can a coding style absolutely guarantee no memory leaks?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, coding-style, c++14

Never using

`new`
`delete`
`release`

and preferring to use

`std::make_unique`
`std::unique_ptr`
`std::move`
`reset` (redundant)

should *morally* result in no memory leaks: new'ed pointers are only ever created inside smart pointers, from which they can never escape, because we have disallowed use of `release`.

One may therefore be tempted into using this coding style, and then never bother checking for memory leaks again - no matter where exceptions may be thrown from, the RAII semantics of the smart pointers should always clean up any dangling pointers as the stack is unwound.

Except C++ is full of nasty surprises. From experience of having my assumptions repeatedly smashed by gotw, I can't help but think that there might be some corner-case which manages to cause a memory leak anyway. Even worse, there might be an obvious way of releasing ownership of the pointer other than `release` itself. Or another smart pointer class *without* an `explicit` constructor which could accidentally ingest the raw pointer obtained via `get`, leading to double frees...

---

Are there any loopholes? If there are, can they be fixed by adding some more simple restrictions? (not allocating any memory doesn't count!) And if a set of coding guidelines that prevents all types of memory errors can be reached, would it be okay to completely forget about the details of memory management?

Comment: Banning usage of `new` and `delete` would well serve for preventing from memory leaks. Supposed smart pointers are used consistently and correct, and usage of raw pointers is banned accordingly.

Comment: Your only source of memory leak after barring explicit dynamic allocation are objects that point at each other. Any time your object relationships require a cycle, the cycle has to be broken in some way.

Comment: Also you might still be stuck with circular references from smart pointers, that would leave you with leaks, but that's not essentially worse than with any garbage collector engine.

Comment: No matter what idiocy you wall off somehow you will find a better idiot. That's evolution, baby. And watch out for third-party libraries.

Comment: It might make you feel better, but the only way to have 100% zero memory leaks is to entirely ban new/delete - and also malloc/free. This is how its done in mission critical systems.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Without pointers you can't write C++ programs.

Comment: @curiousguy That's simply not true.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ A non trivial C++ program without pointer? Please...

Comment: @curiousguy Define _not trivial_, and be explicit about client code must use a pointer please? (I well know that `"Hello World. "` actually comprises a pointer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ For indirection, obviously.

Comment: @curiousguy Your point(er) is irrelevant to the question though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86924/discussion-between-curiousguy-and--).

Comment: @curiousguy Nope! Could not be bothered, discuss here or leave it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Do you suggest that references can replace raw pointers?

Comment: ""Hello World. " actually comprises a pointer." Incorrect. It has array type, not pointer type.

Answer (score 5):

I thought cyclic references were only a problem with `std::shared_ptr`...

```
struct X
{
    std::unique_ptr<X> x;
};

void leak()
{
    auto x = std::make_unique<X>();
    x->x = std::move(x);
}
```

This can be fixed by ensuring that there is no cycle in the graph of types formed by adding an edge from `A` to `B` if and only if `A` contains a member `std::unique_ptr<C>` where `C` is a base of `B`.

Comment: Note that this idiom isn't useless: it can document an object that owns its own lifetime (which are sometimes useful, if lifetime management is tricky).

Answer (score 5):

```
struct evil {
  std::shared_ptr<evil> p; // Alternatively unique_ptr
};
void foo() {
  auto e = std::make_shared<evil>(); // Alternatively make_unique
  e->p = e; // Alternatively std::move(e)
}
int main() {
  for (unsigned i = 1; i != 0; ++i) {
    foo();
    if (i % 100000000)
      std::cout << "I leak\n";
  }
}
```

the above program obeys your restrictions, and leaks like a sieve.

On top of that, undefined behavior can cause leaks.

Comment: In the question, `std::shared_ptr` was not mentioned for this very reason.

Comment: @PBS You asked if banning those calls was enough.  You didn't ban `shared_ptr`.  If you had wanted to ban `shared_ptr`, you shouldn't have "not mentioned" it, you should have banned it?

Comment: Fair point, but now your answer depends on it, I can't fix it!

Comment: @pbs As an aside (old question), replace `shared_ptr` with `unique_ptr` and `make_shared` with `make_unique` and add a `std::move` and the code leaks the same way, for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

> would it be okay to completely forget about the details of memory management?

I'd say the answer to this is going to be *no* in programming for the foreseeable future. Even in garbage collected languages today you can't forget about the details of memory management if you want a performant application.

Memory leaks still happen in garbage collected languages when programs accidentally hang onto references that are no longer needed. Following the rules you set out above for C++ would still be prone to the same issues and is even more likely to be an issue with uses of `shared_ptr`. Common errors of this type are hanging on to objects in a container or through observers for managed references in a garbage collected language or `shared_ptr` in C++.

Comment: If there is still a reachable reference to the memory, it is not a leak.

Comment: Managed / garbage collected applications still leak, they just do it by keeping unintended references alive. If you want to define away leaks in this way feel free but I'd say the common usage is as in the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577534/can-you-have-memory-leaks-with-a-garbage-collector

Comment: You could treat "still hanging onto an unneeded object" the same as "not calling free", but the difference is that the latter can leave you without any way to get the pointer value to free in the future, while the former you can.

Comment: There are much more worrisome cases that cannot be solved by simple rules. Memory fragmentation, for example.

Comment: I agree there are plenty of other reasons to worry about memory management, really my point is that just following a set of rules in C++ or using a garbage collected language is not going to free us from having to think about the details of memory management any time soon.

Comment: @jxh Any case where the ownership of a resource is no longer required by the program going forward is, in essence, a leak.  In C and C++, you can clean up every allocated memory resource: simply end the program.  C++/C leaks can be caused by losing track of every pointer that points to the memory: however, under most implementations, you could just cast an integer to a pointer and free the resource.  Leaks can have other causes.

Comment: @Yakk "_you could just cast an integer to a pointer and free the resource_" I don't get it.

Comment: @Yakk: Yes, in a perversion of my intention, you could read a log file to track down the return value of all allocations, convert the value into a pointer and free it. In such a perversion, yes, I would say there is still technically no leak. Assume there is no way to recover the pointer value. That is a true leak.

Comment: @curiousguy `int* x = new int[1000000]; std::cout << x << '\n'; x = 0;` is a leak.  `std::cout << "Enter pointer to delete:"; uintptr_t px; std::cin >> px; x = (int*)px; delete x;` can "magically" recover a leaked pointer.  (note that this is UB under modern C++, but only recently, due to safely-derived pointer clauses, aka minimal support for gc).

Comment: @jxh there is always a way. You could just generate a random number and get lucky. leaks (in most implementations C++) are a matter of practicality. Other languages (which use other methods to track pointers) may not have the same set of ways to leak, but a leak is any resource that is kept around too long. How long is "too long" is a matter of degree, not kind: all C++ memory "leaks" are recovered at application shutdown (in most implementations). The "it cannot be recovered" is also a matter of degree, not kind. Lazy collectors "leak" for less time than a full C++ leak, but do so more often.

Comment: And yes, this is pedantic: it is about definitions of words.  Saying a language "cannot leak" because all resources can be tracked down means that C++ where you have access to the memory allocation table (say, by overriding `operator new`) "cannot leak".  Which is wrong: the leak is not because it is unreachable, but because *it is not recovered* when it "should" be.  In 90%+ of reasonably written C/C++ programs the two definitions agree; but one of them handles the corner cases much better, and extends into languages that "cannot leak" for similar corner case reasons.

Comment: @Yakk: I am also being pedantic. If you still have a reference to memory that you have erroneously not released because it is no longer needed, that is a logical programming error on the same order of failing to free a pointer that you are about to let forget about. However, since the code still has a handle to that resource, it is conceivable the code path to release it is just not being traversed, not that it wasn't coded. So you don't know that it is a leak, even as your program continues to grow in size. But a dropped reference to allocated memory will never have a chance to be released.

Comment: @Yakk: It clouds the analysis to not make a clear distinction between reachable memory that is not released versus unreachable memory that is not released. The latter are definitely bugs. The former might be bugs, or perhaps the system is just under provisioned.

Comment: Some references for use of 'memory leaks' to refer to "longer lived than desired but reachable" memory in GC languages: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak#Programming_issues https://plumbr.eu/blog/memory-leaks/what-is-a-memory-leak http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MemoryLeakUsingGarbageCollection http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-leaks/ https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/318263

Comment: @Yakk: When you implement your own allocator to help manage memory, just because the only reference left to an allocation resides within that allocator does not automatically deem it reachable. A memory usage analysis tool can very well treat that memory as unreached. I am arguing for a way to correctly classify what kinds of bugs lead to memory bloat problems. Not all memory bloat problems are due to leaks.

Answer (score 1):

There's no guarantee, there's so much that one can screw up ...

- unions ... [(Example)](http://ideone.com/j3YVDp)

  ```
  union Devil {
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr;
    int b;
    Devil () {}
    ~Devil () {
      // no idea what I'm doing
    }
  };
  ```
- Inheritance ... [(Example)](http://ideone.com/1kyaDA)

  ```
  struct Base {};
  struct Derived : public Derived {
   std::unique_ptr<int> ptr;
  };
  // later ...
  std::unique_ptr<Base> p = std::make_unique<Derived>(42);
  // oops
  ```
- playing on the stack ...

  ```
  int f1[10];
  std::unique_ptr<int> p[2];
  int f2[10];
  // later ...
  p[2] = std:: make_unique<int>(42);
  // oops
  ```

... or more generally undefined behaviour. The above is pretty sure only the top of the iceberg ...

Comment: The `unions...` case is defined behavior.  The other two seem like cases of undefined behavior?

Comment: @Yakk The deletion without a virtual destructor in `Base` is definitely UB.

Comment: I'm not sure about the union case, but the others are definitely undefined behaviour. Is it undefined behaviour to not call the destructor of something that's not trivially destructible?

Comment: @DanielJour Of course not. You can overwrite your objects.