# Garbage collector and memory leaks in Java

Tags: java, memory-leaks

After facing some memory leaks in `C/C++` I was wondering if there are memory leaks in `Java`. Quick search brought me to the following [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577534/can-you-have-memory-leaks-with-a-garbage-collector).

The comment of @david-wasser to this thread is:

> ObjectA -> ObjectB
>
> In this example, ObjectA is an object in active use in the code.
>   However, ObjectA contains a reference to ObjectB that is effectively
>   dead (ie: ObjectB has been allocated and used and is now, from the
>   programmer's perspective, dead) but the programmer forgot to set the
>   reference in ObjectA to null. In this case, ObjectB has been "leaked".

I didn't quite get why the garbage collector can't solve this problem? isn't the garbage collector's job is to solve those kind of `memory leaks`?

Also, I would like to see a basic short example which implements this idea.

P.S I prefered to open a new thread about this instead of posting a comment in a 6 years old theard.

Comment: Incidentally, there's nothing wrong with posting a comment on an old answer. If you check the profile of the person you're quoting, you'll even see that they're still active on the site, having used it 4 hours ago.

Comment: Mr Wasser's point was just that if ObjectA is still accessible, and ObjectA has a reference to ObjectB, then ObjectB is still accessible.  This is the way it should be.  It's actually quite difficult to create a memory leak in Java - I do know of at least one case where a programmer inadvertently leaked some memory, but obviously, it's much less likely to happen in Java than it is in C or C++.

Comment: Garbage collectors can delete objects that are no longer referenced.  But they can't do anything about objects that are _still referenced_ but will not be _used_ anymore.

Answer (score 0):

GC only collects objects which are no longer referenced from the program, as the reference of objectB in objectA is not set to null it is never eligible for GC.

GC would never know if the objectB is a grabage or not as the code keeps to hold a reference to it.